# Error creating VDPAU device: 1

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, vdpau

my GPU Geforce 920M supports multiple video codex according the the official docs

http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/418.56/README/supportedchips.html

http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/418.56/README/vdpausupport.html

I followed the instructions installing  libvdpau , VDPAU , and installed the latest NVIDIA graphics from ubuntu repository

[image]

although my system can't identify any video decoder on my NVIDIA GPU how to fix this problem

```
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ export VDPAU_NVIDIA_DEBUG=3
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ export VDPAU_TRACE=1
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so /usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so
[sudo] password for joseph: 
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so': File exists
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ sudo mv /usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so.backup /usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so
mv: cannot stat '/usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so.backup': No such file or directory
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so /usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so': File exists
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ sudo mv /usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so.backup /usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so
mv: cannot stat '/usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so.backup': No such file or directory
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ vdpauinfo 
display: :0   screen: 0
VDPAU capture: Enabled
vdp_imp_device_create_x11(0x55731ce33e70, 0, -, -)
GPU at BusId 0x1 doesn't have a supported video decoder
VDPAU nvidia: Version: NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  418.56  Fri Mar 15 12:31:51 CDT 2019
VDPAU nvidia: Error detected 9 373  3
VDPAU nvidia: Backtrace:
--: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 [0x7fb72d51d000] DSO load base
00: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 [0x7fb72d55551c] 
01: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 [0x7fb72d544033] 
02: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 [0x7fb72d5274f1] vdp_imp_device_create_x11
    -> 1
Error creating VDPAU device: 1
```

here is when using MPV player to play a youtube video this is the output

```
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ export VDPAU_TRACE_FILE=mplayer.log
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ export VDPAU_TRACE_FILE=mpv.log
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Spk6GyOzjwQ
bash: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Spk6GyOzjwQ: No such file or directory
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ sudo nano .config/mpv/mpv.conf 
joseph@joseph-X541UJ:~$ mpv https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Spk6GyOzjwQ
Playing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Spk6GyOzjwQ
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 1920x1080 60.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) 'DASH audio' (opus 2ch 48000Hz) (external)
GPU at BusId 0x1 doesn't have a supported video decoder
VDPAU nvidia: Version: NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  418.56  Fri Mar 15 12:31:51 CDT 2019
VDPAU nvidia: Error detected 9 373  3
VDPAU nvidia: Backtrace:
--: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 [0x7f296517c000] DSO load base
00: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 [0x7f29651b451c] 
01: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 [0x7f29651a3033] 
02: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 [0x7f29651864f1] vdp_imp_device_create_x11
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz stereo 2ch float
[ffmpeg/video] h264: Hardware is lacking required capabilities
[ffmpeg/video] h264: Failed setup for format cuda: hwaccel initialisation returned error.
VO: [gpu] 1920x1080 yuv420p
AV: 00:00:57 / 00:32:30 (2%) A-V:  0.000 Dropped: 24 Cache: 46s+32MB
[ffmpeg] NULL: Invalid NAL unit size (5001 > 2466).
[ffmpeg] NULL: missing picture in access unit with size 2470


Exiting... (Quit)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the driver so can't help you there :(  Looks like it seems to partly pick the integrated intel gpu and not the nvidia.

Comment: @Rinzwind I've installed NVIDIA driver manually disabling nouva intel drivers completely 

and the problem is still present do you think I've to wait for future NVIDIA driver release till this problem is fixed ?

Comment: Likely yes. There is a nvidia dev forum.  https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/523241/linux/if-you-have-a-problem-with-vdpau-and-or-mplayer-vdpau-please-read-this-first/ has some instruction. Maybe that is a better place to get their attention. Sorry wish we could fix this :( The 1st part of that topic might be worth while you might try to play a video and see what happens then

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks very much for your help I've sent them an email on linux-bugs@nvidia.com
with the file generated by nvidia-bug-report 
it looks like that NVIDIA doesn't support linux system very well and all I've to do now is waiting and using intel drivers really shame on nvidia 
also I've edited my questions and added some info which you may look at 

MPV say" Hardware is lacking required capabilities"
what does this means